# DynamicUpdate added extra untouched column in update statement

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am facing a weird behavior using @DynamicUpdate with one of my entity. So my entity is defined like this

```java
@Entity
@DynamicUpdate
@Table(name = "courts")
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor // require for @Builder to work correctly
@NoArgsConstructor // required for hibernate mapping
public class CourtDO {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    // name is SQL keyword
    @Column(name = "court_name")
    private String name;

    @Column
    private String addressStreet;

    @Column
    private String addressWard;

    @Column
    private String addressDistrict;

    @Column
    private String addressCity;

    @Column
    private String addressCountry;

    @Column
    private String phoneNumber;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Convert(converter = DOTimestampConverter.class)
    @CreationTimestamp
    private ZonedDateTime createdAt;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Convert(converter = DOTimestampConverter.class)
    @UpdateTimestamp
    private ZonedDateTime updatedAt;
}
```

`DOTimestampConverter` is just a simple `AttributeConverter` to convert `ZonedDateTime` to ms for me to store in DB as number.

As you can see I marked the entity with `@DynamicUpdate`.

I have a small jersey REST-API which allow me to update all of the normal field beside the id and the generated date. I always check if the input is `null` before actually touching the setter for the field.

I see a very weird behavior with the column `address_city`, it would be included in every update like this even if I only touch other fields, in this case, just the `name` which translate to `court_name` because `name` is a reserved keyword in SQL. **UPDATE** Actually the problem is not with just the `address_city` column. Even if I ignore that column, other column would get included in the update statement.

```
Hibernate: 
    update
        courts 
    set
        address_city=?,
        court_name=?,
        updated_at=? 
    where
        id=?
```

Where as if I only edit the `address_city` only then I would see it correctly

```
Hibernate: 
    update
        courts 
    set
        address_city=?,
        updated_at=? 
    where
        id=?
```

Did anyone face this problem before?
The stack I am using are

```
spring-boot 2.1.3.RELEASE
spring-boot-starter-data-jpa
postgresql 11.4
```

And the data schema

```sql
CREATE TABLE COURTS (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    court_name VARCHAR(20),
    address_street VARCHAR(128),
    address_ward VARCHAR(20),
    address_district VARCHAR(20),
    address_city VARCHAR(20),
    address_country VARCHAR(10),
    phone_number VARCHAR(20),
    created_at BIGINT NOT NULL,
    updated_at BIGINT NOT NULL
);
```

This is how update through REST-API

```
@Override
    public Court editCourt(String courtId, CreateCourtRequest createCourtRequest) {
        Optional<CourtDO> court = courtRepository.findById(NumberUtils.toLong(courtId));

        return court
            .map(courtDO -> editCourtInfo(courtDO, createCourtRequest))
            .map(courtRepository::save)
            .map(courtDOToResponseConverter::convert)
            .orElse(null);
    }

    private CourtDO editCourtInfo(CourtDO courtDO, CreateCourtRequest createCourtRequest) {
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(createCourtRequest.getName())) {
            courtDO.setName(createCourtRequest.getName());
        }

        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(createCourtRequest.getAddressStreet())) {
            courtDO.setAddressStreet(createCourtRequest.getAddressStreet());
        }

        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(createCourtRequest.getAddressWard())) {
            courtDO.setAddressWard(createCourtRequest.getAddressWard());
        }

        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(createCourtRequest.getAddressDistrict())) {
            courtDO.setAddressDistrict(createCourtRequest.getAddressDistrict());
        }

        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(createCourtRequest.getAddressCity())) {
            courtDO.setAddressCity(createCourtRequest.getAddressCity());
        }

        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(createCourtRequest.getPhoneNumber())) {
            courtDO.setPhoneNumber(createCourtRequest.getPhoneNumber());
        }

        return courtDO;
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide details on how the value in the entity is updated by the REST-API?

Comment: I have tried and it is not updating other fields
2019-07-31 10:02:39.299 DEBUG 11569 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : update courts set court_name=? where id=?

Comment: @YogeshPrajapati do you mind try exact my setting? https://github.com/nhatnguyen26/zooProject/tree/FieldManage

Comment: I start to suspect there could be a bug with hibernate version, as I tried to override the version at `5.4.4.Final` instead of the default `5.3.7.Final` then the problem kind of go away